# How to conditionally deserialize JSON to two different variants of an enum?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Let's say I have JSON data like the following:

```
{
  "type": "A",
  "value": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
}
```

```
{
  "type": "B",
  "value": [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ] ]
}
```

`type` determines the type of `value`, which in the first example is `Vec<u32>` and in the second is `Vec<Vec<u32>>`.

If I represent the above data as follows:

```rust
enum DataValue {
  TypeA(Vec<u32>),
  TypeB(Vec<Vec<u32>>)
}

struct Data {
  data_type: String,
  value: DataValue
}
```

How do I implement serde deserialization to properly decode these values?

Comment: well... like that xd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can deserialize your JSON data directly to an instance of `DataValue` if you give Serde enough information to know how to do this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "value")]
enum DataValue {
    #[serde(rename = "A")]
    TypeA(Vec<u32>),
    #[serde(rename = "B")]
    TypeB(Vec<Vec<u32>>),
}

let data_a = r#"
    {
        "type": "A",
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }"#;
let a: DataValue = serde_json::from_str(data_a)?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d8a5d4058ea519523a9beb41a335262)

If you name your enum variants `A` and `B`, you can omit the `#[serde(rename = "…")]` attributes.

This way of serializing enums is called "adjacent tagging". You can learn about the various options of tagging enums in the [Serde documentation on enum serialization](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html).

Your `Data` struct contains a redundant additional tag `data_type`. This information is already encoded in the enum, so I don't think you need this. If you need this information as a string, you can add a method to the enum:

```
impl DataValue {
    fn variant_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            DataValue::TypeA(_) => "A",
            DataValue::TypeB(_) => "B",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately `serde` has build-in support for [enum type](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged):

```rust
//# serde = { version = "1.0.99", features = ["derive"] }
//# serde_json = "1.0.40"

use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Data {
    A { value: Vec<u32> },
    B { value: Vec<Vec<u32>> },
}

fn main() {
    let a: Data = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"type": "A", "value": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]}"#).unwrap();
    let b: Data =
        serde_json::from_str(r#"{"type": "B", "value": [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8 ]]}"#).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Answer (score -7):

This may be a person opinion but I would generally try to avoid serialization / deserialization on enums.

Would this not be close to the same thing in C++?

```
struct DataValue final{
  TypeA(Vec<u32>) final,
  TypeB(Vec<Vec<u32>>) final
}
```

Comment: That's... not even legal C++? It's not clear to me what argument you're making besides "don't do that", which is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This neither fits the expression of the problem nor   semantically make sense. Even after pretending it is valid C++, it would say that you have both TypeA and TypeB data valid. This represents a huge class of bugs in software. Please unlearn this and do not perpetuate this.