# How deserialize an enum with generic types using serde

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am trying to deserialize the following struct (`BaseResponse<T, E>`):

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct BaseResponse<T, E> {
    result: BaseResponseResult,
    error_code: u32,
    error_message: String,
    content: BaseResponseContent<T, E>,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum BaseResponseResult {
    Success,
    Error,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum BaseResponseContent<T, E> {
    Success(T),
    Error(E),
}
```

The aforementioned struct has a type `T` and a type `E` these types are found in the field `content` when:

- The field result is `success`: `T`
- The field result is `error`: `E`

In order to group these two generic types, I have used the `BaseResponseContent` enum.

For example, let's take into account the following response content types.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct User {
    username: String,
    location: String,
    age: u32,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct FailedLookup {
    ip: String,
    time: String,
}
```

If the request is successful, the API will respond with a result `success` and a `User` object:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": "",
    "content": {
        "username": "someone",
        "location": "somewhere",
        "age": 20
    }
}
```

If the request fails the API will respond with a result `error` and a `FailedLookup` object:

```
{
    "result": "error",
    "error_code": 404,
    "error_message": "no such user",
    "content": {
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "time": "1624352175"
    }
}
```

How may I implement deserialize for `BaseResponseContent` or use `deserialize_with` on the `content` field in `BaseResponse` so that the type `BaseResponseContent::Success(T)` will be deserialized on `success` and `BaseResponseContent::Error(E)` will be deserialized on `error`?

One thing is clear, deriving `Deserialize` for BaseResponseContent is not enough as the deserializer will be looking for a field named `Success` or `Error` inside `content`.

```
Error: unknown variant `username`, expected `Success` or `Error` at line 1 column 78
```

[Here you have a full demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3aa91ed05232da1564d9c761a14f616f)

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639162/how-to-conditionally-deserialize-json-to-two-different-variants-of-an-enum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally deserialize JSON to two different variants of an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639162/how-to-conditionally-deserialize-json-to-two-different-variants-of-an-enum)

Comment: Your question does not contain the problematic code, only parts of it. Those parts do not compile because you are deriving `Clone` for a struct containing a `String`. This makes it harder than it needs to be for us to debug your problem. Please supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also be interested in the section "Producing a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE) for Rust code" in the [Rust tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info).

Comment: @sk_pleasant I had already provided a link to an MRE in Rust Playground

Comment: @so61pi and Masklinn Thanks for the references. I had already seen that question but I was missing the #[serde(flatten)] tag that jonasbb uses in his answer.

Comment: @PauMAVA Damn, you're right. Sorry, seems I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantic duplication between `BaseResponseResult` and `BaseResponseContent` makes this a bit harder. If possible, I would remove the `result` field from `BaseResponse`. Instead, the variants of `BaseResponseContent` contain the same information.

The fields `result` and `content` then match an [adjacently tagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged). [`flatten`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#flatten) inlines the fields into `BaseResponse`.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct BaseResponse<T, E> {
    error_code: u32,
    error_message: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    content: BaseResponseContent<T, E>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case", tag = "result", content = "content")]
pub enum BaseResponseContent<T, E> {
    Success(T),
    Error(E),
}
```

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82d0a0c2340ba5a0c9028ff7a004e1e3)

If the `result` field needs to exist and cannot be replaced by other means, e.g., a function call, I would first deserialize into the above structure and then convert it into the final struct.